# How to change the state of the image in cell made in xib?

Tags: swift, xcode

There is a `TableView` and a "Locked" image, how do I get `alpha = 0` when I click cell 1 in cell 2? There is the `cellForRowAt` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.commonInit("got_\(indexPath.item)", title: titleLessons[indexPath.item], sub: summary[indexPath.item], imageLock: imageZ[indexPath.item])


    return cell
}
```

There is the `didSelectRowAt` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if unlockedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
        let nextIndex = indexPath.row + 1
        if nextIndex < pdfArr.count {
            let vc = DetailLessonsVC()
            let ce = TableViewCell()

            vc.pdfTitle = pdfArr[indexPath.row]

            vc.numberList = pdfArr[indexPath.row]

            vc.linkList = link[indexPath.row]

            unlockedRows.append(indexPath.row + 1)

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)   
        }
        print("no")
    }     
}
```

`TableViewCell` is xib's custom class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the cell, and change image property, you can access the cell in didselect method with this:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cell's custom class (TableViewCell) create an outlet for your image. If I understand correctly you want to edit cell located in the row number N+1 when user taps on the cell located in the row above, right? 
If that's the case then all you have to do is get a reference to the next cell in `didSelectRowAt`. You can do just that this way:

```
var nextCellsIndexPath = indexPath
        nextCellsIndexPath.row += 1
        // Use 'if let' in order to make sure the cell at that index path exists
        if let nexCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextCellsIndexPath) {
            nextCell.lockedImage.alpha = 0 
        }
```

Since you didn't specify the number of sections in your table view, I assumed it has just one.